# Kotlin Android Extensions plug-in doesn't work occasionally

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-extension

As shown in the screenshot below, why is it that the Kotlin Android Extensions plug-in (used for binding views) doesn't get recognized throughout my project's UI classes (Activity/Fragment)? This particularly happened when viewing in-between multiple Android Studio project windows, but now it's beginning to happen occasionally within a single project. I was wondering if there's a workaround for this because as of now, I'd have to keep cleaning and rebuilding my project to continue from where I left off. If not, I guess this is just a bug.

Oh, and I'm using the latest Kotlin plug-in v1.2.41 for both my Gradle and IDE platform.

[image]

*** UPDATE: I figured out that this mainly happens in the latest stable release of Android Studio v3.1.1, so I've been using the latest preview version of Studio v3.2 which works fine. Either way, I reported an issue to Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79615649 ***

Comment: So apparently some other colleagues of mine are experiencing the same issue... I reported this as a potential bug to Google in the meantime!

Comment: Having same issue, a gradle sync usually fixes it.
Can you post the ling to the bug you reported ?

Comment: @RickSanchez https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79615649

Comment: I still have this problem with Studio v3.2, Usually after the window is switched.